# Merge multiple scopes into one

Tags: angularjs

I have two scopes,

```
$scope.moviesFromActor = $scope.moviesFromActorResponse.credits.cast
$scope.moviesFromActorCrew = $scope.moviesFromActorResponse.credits.crew
```

I would like to use both results in one `ng-repeat`, so I was thinking I need to merge all the objects in both scopes, into one scope.

What would be the best way to achieve this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **[`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)** list into one and display that list in the `ng-repeat`

Likt this

```
$scope.movie=$scope.moviesFromActorResponse.credits.cast.concat($scope.moviesFromActorResponse.credits.crew);
```

Comment: Thanks, seems to be working fine. Learn something every day.